# Не находит путь до css файлов

Tags: java, html, css, spring

Делаю сайт на Spring.Есть страница html,при запуске не отображается графическая часть,а только формы ввода,полагаю дело в том,что java не находит путь до css файлов,проверьте пожалуйста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вопрос непонятен. Опишите проблему подробнее и не приводите в вопросе картинки, приводите тексты. Читайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask и другие темы из раздела https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

У вас скорее всего не настроены так называемые [статические](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot) ресурсы. Измените структуру проекта, так что бы весь статический контент был размещен в одной директории с одним из стандартных зарезервированных названий("/META-INF/resources/", "/resources/", "/static/", "/public/"). 
После этого браузер начнет "видеть" ваши файлы css-стилей.

P.S.: для доступа к этим файлам из контролера воспользуйтесь классом `ClassPathResource`, например:

```
@RestController
public class ImageLoaderRestController {
    @GetMapping(value = "/api/image")
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getImage(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String name)
            throws IOException {

        ClassPathResource imgFile = new ClassPathResource("/META-INF/resources/static/image/" + name + ".png",
                Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());

        return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG)
                .body(new InputStreamResource(imgFile.getInputStream()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - У вас на странице 2 раза используется `<body>`

2 - Проверьте, что ваши файлы правильно разбросаны в разделе `resourses`.
Пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3 - Используте Thymeleaf. (об этом почитате в интернете.)
Для добавления CSS в вашем случае это будет:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{css/style.css}">
```

4 - Если у вас подключен Spring Security, то добавьте следующие строки:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**");
}
```

Это должно быть вставлено там же, где и класс с `extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`